# Documentation for nautilus and GIO's .hidden file feature?

Tags: gio, nautilus

I just discovered some mentions of how nautilus used to read files named `.hidden` and hide files matching the patterns listed in them, and at some point that feature was moved to GIO `g_file_info_get_is_hidden`.  However, I haven't been able to get it to work.  If I put the exact name of a file into `.hidden`, it does get hidden, but I'd really like to be able to use a pattern.  I can't find any solid or recent documentation about how this feature is supposed to work.

I'd particularly like to hide files matching `hg-checkexec-*`. Mercurial running under Emacs periodically creates bunches of these temporary files and they gum up my nautilus view.

Is this feature documented anywhere? How is it supposed to work?

Answer (score 3):

[Looking at the code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/blob/main/gio/glocalfileinfo.c#L1704), `.hidden` files as implemented in GIO support one filename per line, with no support for patterns. A `.hidden` file cannot list files in subdirectories — only those in the same directory.

I don’t know of any documentation about the feature. Please [file a bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=glib&component=gio) about adding it.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to [Philip Withnall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42622810/624066), I've dived further into the source code, specifically the functions `read_hidden_file()` and `file_is_hidden()`:

- `read_hidden_file()` basically parses the `.hidden` in a directory and stores each line in as a key in a [GLib HashTable](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.HashTable.html) object.

  - The object is created using [`g_hash_table_new_full()`](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/type_func.HashTable.new_full.html) with parameters `g_str_hash, g_str_equal, g_free, NULL`. This mean keys are plain strings with comparison being a plain (case-sensitive) string equality, so no globs, regex or any patterns support.
  - It is populated using [`g_hash_table_add()`](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/type_func.HashTable.add.html), so not used as a key/value pair *table* but rather as a plain ***set***, with keys being the elements themselves.
- `file_is_hidden()` is called for each content (file or sub-directory) in a given directory. It uses [`g_hash_table_contains()`](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/type_func.HashTable.contains.html) to check if the file's *basename* is a *key* in above object, so no pattern search whatsoever.

So, as Phillip concluded, it seems there is indeed no support for any kind of globs, regexes or pattern seach in `.hidden` files. I would also die for a `.gitignore`-like syntax.